# how to get the total count of a products in a wishlist in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, wishlist

I want to get the **total** count of **products** in a **wishlist** without calculating the same product twice

in wishlist_item.js file
decorateItems: function() {
var items = this.wishlist().items;
if (typeof items === 'undefined' || !items.length) return;
$('a.action.towishlist').each(function(){
var data = $(this).data('post'),
i;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
if (parseInt(data.data.product) == parseInt(items[i].product_id)) {
$(this).addClass('selected');
}
}
});
} I have added this code it keeps counting the same product if i add that product to the wishlist

Comment: Did you try my answer? @eswar

Comment: i tried with u r answer.thank u for u help.

Comment: You can accept the answer If its help you @eswar

Answer (score 2):

```
.....
protected $wishlistProvider;
.....

public function __construct(
.....
\Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider
.....
){
......
$this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
......
}


public function execute()
{
......
$currentUserWishlist = $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist();
if ($currentUserWishlist) {
     $wishlistItems = $currentUserWishlist->getItemCollection();
}
$wishlistItemCounts = $wishlistItems->count();
.......
}
```

Here, `$this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist();` is used to get current user wishlist.

`$wishlistItemCounts` will get you total counts of wishlist items.

Comment: but i want for current logged in customer wishlist count

Comment: Yes @eswar .. $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist(); will give you count of logged in customer only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`loadByCustomerId()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php#L193) from `\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist` class

```
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;


protected $wishlistFactory;


public function __construct(
    ...
    WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
    CustomerSession $customerSession,   
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;  
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    ....
}
```

Now you can get it like,

```
$wishlist = $this->wishlistFactory->create()
           ->loadByCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId());

    if($wishlist) {
         $count = $wishlist->getCount()                     
      }
```